# Slick-carousel - How To Pause and Play embedded Youtube videos on slide Change?

Tags: jquery, youtube, slick.js, youtube-iframe-api

I want to create a Slick slider with Youtube videos, So I can use youtube iFrame embed code directly to slides, and it will work, But what I want to achieve is When the slide changes Video should stop/pause playing.

I am using Slick Slider.

Here Is the HTML I am Using::

```
<div class="entry_slider_video">
     <div data-thumb="http://placehold.it/140x100">
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gLJdzky63BA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
     <div data-thumb="http://placehold.it/140x100"><iframe width="420" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tf4sa0BVJVw?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
<div data-thumb="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    <iframe width="420" height="315"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QF903RaKLvs?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
  </div>
```

And the JS:::

```
$('.entry_slider_video').slick({
              arrows: false,
              fade: true,
              autoplay: true,
              dots: true,
              customPaging : function(slider, i) {
                  var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb');
                  return '<a class="enty_thumbs"><img src="'+thumb+'"></a>';
                }
 });
```

I know I have to use Youtube API(https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) inorder achieve this, I have tried some of the solutions from SO, but no luck. any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `beforeChange` event of Slick and send a postMessage to the contentWindow of the iframe. In Code this could look like:

```
$('.entry_slider_video').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var data = {"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""};
    var message = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("iframe", slick.$slides[currentSlide])[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
});
```

Don't forget to add the parameter `enablejsapi=1` to the url of the video. The first video in your example doesn't have it.

Comment: there is a simple question.... now whenever slide changes video get pused event though video is not playing, that makes a blank black screen, Is there any method to check is video playing, is playing apply Pause else Stop

Comment: You have two options: 
1. Include the Youtube Api and listen for the `onStateChange` event. 
2. Listen for postMessages like in this example http://simplestexplanation.com/2014/04/youtube-iframe-api-without-external-script/ . 

You have to keep track of every video and it's state. So probably the best way is to give every iframe it's own id and store it in an associative array key = id and value = state. Then you should be able to check the state of the current video inside the `beforChange` event of the slider.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable point, I will give it a try and update here.