# Slick Carousel - Pause the slider's autoplay when a YouTube video is playing

Tags: youtube-api, slick.js

With [slick.js](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I am able to pause a playing YouTube video after advancing to the next slide.

However, I can't figure out how to pause the slider's `autoplay` function (`slickPause`) on the slider itself while the video is playing.

Then, resume `autoplay` on the slider only after the video has finished or when the user advances to a different slide.

Please help!

```
(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".hero-slider").on("beforeChange", function(event, slick) {
            var currentSlide, slideType, player, command;
            currentSlide = $(slick.$slider).find(".slick-current");
            slideType = currentSlide.attr("class").split(" ")[1];

            player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
            if (slideType == "vimeo") {
                command = {
                    "method": "pause",
                    "value": "true"
                };
            } else {
                command = {
                    "event": "command",
                    "func": "pauseVideo",
                    "args": ""
                };
            }
            if (player != undefined) {
                player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
            }
        });
        $(".hero-slider").slick({
            infinite: true,
            arrows: true,
            dots: false,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,
            focusOnSelect: true
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [sample code](https://github.com/colineforde/colineforde.github.io/blob/5f73b891a7cc7dc46e543438b2491ce8f84c835c/projects/cheat-sheet.js). You can use `slickPause` like this:

```
$('.hero-slider').click(function() {
  $('.hero-slider').slick('slickPause');
});
```

Also, here are some references which might help:

- [Slick-carousel - How To Pause and Play embedded Youtube videos on slide Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978087/slick-carousel-how-to-pause-and-play-embedded-youtube-videos-on-slide-change)
- [Slick-carousel how to stop autoplay when video is on via youtube api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071623/slick-carousel-how-to-stop-autoplay-when-video-is-on-via-youtube-api/30071762)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already looked at those references. They don't offer any new insight which answers my question. Specifying pause onclick is fine, however, that stops the slider from autoplaying entirely. I need the slider to autoplay when the video has finished or if the video has been paused.